# How do I write an error message in BASH for a specific input?

Tags: bash

I am new to BASH, well scripting in general, and am writing a BASH script but no idea what to do

I have a script working currently, where with specifics user inputs, it writes a file for a subsequent software to work.

However, specific numbers and phrases are needed for the software to work, so I want to write an error message, that if the input isn't correct, instead of the script failing and starting from scratch, an error message is shown and you have a redo

```sh
##Writing inp.add Files##
printf "\n${bold}Writing inp.add file\n${normal}"
read -p "Number of Processors: " NPROC
read -p "Wavefunction File (with .wfx): " WFX
read -p "Coord file (CUBE or .txt): " COORD
echo "AOM_MAT OCCUP automatically picked"
read -p "Overlap (LO or LDO): " OVERLAP
printf "\nRunning Gaussian: ${bold}$JOBNAME \n${normal}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while cond ; do ... done`:

```
while true ; do
    read -p "Input var: " var
    [[ -n "$var" ]] && break
    echo "Please enter a non-empty value"
done
echo "You entered $var"
```

Will ask for input until it's non-empty.

Comment: Thats not exactly what i meant. for example in the part of the code:

read -p "Overlap (LO or LDO): " OVERLAP

the only options for the software is LO and LDO, so if one of the 2 arent entered, then an error message is needed and repeat that question

Comment: @ThomasBates you should edit your question with that remark, it makes it *a lot* different, and probably not a duplicate anymore.

Comment: well i can't find the question that i apparently duplicated so the flag doesnt help me

Comment: @ThomasBates The four duplicates are linked at the top of the question.

Comment: my apologies, I am new to this website

Comment: FYI you don't need [[ 1 == 1 ]] you can just use [[ 1 ]]

Comment: @MikeQ thanks, I thought so but couldn't test it easily here...

Comment: Actually you don't need `[[` either. The idiomatic endless loop is `while true` or even `while :`

Comment: @tripleee now that you say it, I remember using that a few years ago!